# Error: Result 1 must be a single string, not a character vector of length 0 when using "make_choose_all_table" from tidyREDCap

Tags: r, redcap

I am receiving an error when using `make_choose_all_table()` from the `tidyREDCap` package and I'm hoping someone can help me understand what it means. When I export my data from REDCap using `REDCapR` and then run the code `make_choose_all_table()` the error below it pops up. The "boo_do_co_no" is my checkbox variable that I am trying to make a table with.

What does the error mean and how do I fix it?

```
library(REDCapR)
data <- redcap_read()

library(tidyREDCap)
make_choose_all_table(data, "boo_do_co_no")
Error: Result 1 must be a single string, not a character vector of length 0
```

It needs to come out like the picture below
[image]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you are missing an argument within `data <- redcap_read()` When I run that line, `data` contains the function code for `redcap_read()`, not any data output that might come from the function when all the arguments are specified.

See `?redcap_read()`

Comment: This is the right answer.  The required parameters are documented also at https://ouhscbbmc.github.io/REDCapR/reference/redcap_read.html.  A trouble-shooting guide and other vignettes are here: https://ouhscbbmc.github.io/REDCapR/articles